# Working with relations between forms in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to learn how to insert relational content on `model/add` page with `CakePHP 1.3`. I've found very easy and intuitive the creation of base content like `user registration`, `post creation` as I've saw in the [book.cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/) but I have some doubt when I shoud insert some `transaction` with relational contents.

For example, I could have a `post` with many `photos` linked to it I like to upload from the url `mysite.com/posts/add`.

Does exist some pratical example somewhere on the web which talks about this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, your `posts/add` would have a way of uploading an arbritary number of images that would be tied to the paticular post but are stored in their own model (say `photos`)?

I don't think there is any prebuilt way to do this, since most of the functions I've seen for dealing with related data seem to involve reading data, not writing it.

You could manually save all those photos as you're using the Photo model's save action.
Such as:

```
$this->Post->save($this->data);
for ($this->data['Photos'] as $photo) {
    $this->Post->Photo->save($photo);
}
```

or even:

```
$this->Post->save($this->data);
$this->Post->Photos->saveAll($this->data); //Or something. I don't have access to the syntax right now
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to CakePHP so I don't know exaclty how to do stuff, I'll try this way.